# How to exclude ncurses when building Emacs from source

Tags: build

I have a building environment/setup that contains `ncurses`, and I am looking to build Emacs master branch **without** that library.  I did not see any obvious option in the `.configure --help` dialog, or by Googling.

**Q**:  How, please, can I tell Emacs during the `configure` process to forget about `ncurses` -- i.e., pretend that it doesn't exist?

**Background**:  When the building environment contains `ncurses`, an Emacs version built from that environment will always look for it when it launches.  If `ncurses` is not there, Emacs fails to launch.  I would like to build Emacs that does not look for `ncurses` each time it launches.  `gdb` confirms that Emacs is looking for `ncurses`.  The only workaround I have found is to remove `ncurses` entirely from my building environment, which is not an ideal solution.

I've tried excluding everything I can think of, but Emacs is still looking for `ncurses` when it launches:

```
./configure \
--with-ns \
--without-dbus \
--without-gconf \
--without-gif \
--without-gnutls \
--without-gpm \
--without-imagemagick \
--without-jpeg \
--without-libotf \
--without-makeinfo \
--without-m17n-flt \
--without-png \
--without-rsvg \
--without-gsettings \
--without-sound \
--without-tiff \
--without-x \
--without-xaw3d \
--without-xft \
--without-xml2 \
--without-xpm \
--without-zlib \
--with-file-notification=no \
--disable-acl \
--enable-checking='glyphs' \
--without-compress-install
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone better acquainted will have a definitive answer, but a quick isearch through the `configure` script suggests the `LIBS_TERMCAP` environment variable controls this, and alternative values are `LIBS_TERMCAP="-ltinfo"` or `LIBS_TERMCAP="-ltermcap"` and that you may or may not also need `TERMINFO=no`.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll be able to try those out later this evening and will report back -- greatly appreciated.